# Linq find differences in two lists

Tags: linq, set

I have two list of members like this:

Before: Peter, Ken, Julia, Tom

After: Peter, Robert, Julia, Tom

As you can see, Ken is is out and Robert is in.

What I want is to detect the changes. I want a list of what has changed in both lists. How can linq help me?

Comment: I think you need to define "change" a little more.  Is a change in order of items a "change" to you, for example?

Answer (score 29):

Your question is not completely specified but I assume that you are looking for the differences as sets (that is, ordering does not matter). If so, you want the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the two sets. You can achieve this using [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
before.Except(after).Union(after.Except(before));
```

Answer (score 23):

As an alternative to linq answers, which have to pass both lists twice, use [HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848.aspx):

```
var difference = new HashSet(before);
difference.SymmetricExceptWith(after);
```

Could be considerably more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
before.Union(after).Except(before.Intersect(after))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version having O(n) complexity, provided your sequences are both ordered:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> SymmetricDifference<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll1, IEnumerable<T> coll2, IComparer<T> cmp)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enum1 = coll1.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<T> enum2 = coll2.GetEnumerator())
        {
            bool enum1valid = enum1.MoveNext();
            bool enum2valid = enum2.MoveNext();
            while (enum1valid && enum2valid)
            {
                int cmpResult = cmp.Compare(enum1.Current, enum2.Current);
                if (cmpResult < 0)
                {
                    yield return enum1.Current;
                    enum1valid = enum1.MoveNext();
                }
                else if (cmpResult > 0)
                {
                    yield return enum2.Current;
                    enum2valid = enum2.MoveNext();
                }
                else
                {
                    enum1valid = enum1.MoveNext();
                    enum2valid = enum2.MoveNext();
                }
            }
            while (enum1valid)
            {
                yield return enum1.Current;
                enum1valid = enum1.MoveNext();
            }
            while (enum2valid)
            {
                yield return enum2.Current;
                enum2valid = enum2.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }


    public static IEnumerable<T> SymmetricDifference<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll1, IEnumerable<T> coll2)
    {
        return SymmetricDifference(coll1, coll2, Comparer<T>.Default);
    }
```

Comment: This would work only for sorted sequences, right? One cannot make symdiff in just O(n) for arbitrary sequences.

Comment: Sure it does, just look at the co-iteration. It is slightly modified version of sequential-merge from merge-sort. Although it will not work for unsorted, it is _very_ efficient for sorted, so in many cases it will be faster and more memory-friendly to pre-sort the collection and then use this filter ~> n + 2*(n log n) instead of some naiive all-vs-all n^2 or some hashtable memory hogs ..in case of _many_ elements of course:)