# How does LINQ Except work?

Tags: linq, except

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [LINQ find differences in two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404301/linq-find-differences-in-two-lists)

I want to find a difference between 2 series. So I am using `Except` in the LINQ statement. But `Except` seems to work only when the first collection is longer than the second. For example this will not return any result, even though the 2 collections are different.

```
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers2.Except(numbers1);
```

Can anyone confirm if this is the case? If so, do I have to check the collection lengths before I write the query, because I do not know which collection will be bigger at compile time.

Edit

I think I was not clear in my question. I do not care which collection contains what. I just want to find difference between 2 collections. How can I do this?

Comment: I am not sure whats happening here - but somebody seems to be markinq negative votes to questions/answers.

Comment: Difference how so? `Except` is not symmetric. Are you looking for A.Difference(B) returning everything in A that isn't in B *and* everything in B that isn't in A...or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I found the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404301/linq-find-differences-in-two-lists

Answer (score 62):

Taken from [101 LINQ Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/try-samples/101-linq-samples/):

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 }; 
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 }; 

IEnumerable<int> aOnlyNumbers = numbersA.Except(numbersB); 

Console.WriteLine("Numbers in first array but not second array:"); 
foreach (var n in aOnlyNumbers) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(n); 
}
```

**Result**

Numbers in first array but not second array:
0
2
4
6
9

Answer (score 11):

> For example this will not return any result...

That's correct.

`2.2` exists in the first collection, so there is nothing to return.

It has nothing to do with the lengths of the arrays.

Comment: they've misunderstood how it works, they are expecting it to return the items from A and B that aren't equal so if A was {1,2{ and B was {2,3} they are expecting Except to return {1, 3} the wording on the MSDN site is ambiguous

Answer (score 8):

The other answers are telling you how you can remove a set of numbers from another set. Reading your question I think you want what's in the first but not in the second, and viceversa:

```
var numbers1 = new [] { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
var numbers2 = new [] { 2.2, 2.8 };

var intersect = numbers1.Intersect(numbers2);
var diff = numbers1.Concat(numbers2).Except(intersect);
```