# Where is the source for System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList()?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking to see if putting a  `.ToList()` on an `IEnumerable` which might or might not be a list will incur a performance hit if the `Object` is already a `List`.

My Goal was to look at the source code. and this is where the tunnel of questions begins. First I found SO Question [Where can I view LINQ source code? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750985/where-can-i-view-linq-source-code) this leads to the Full Framework version of DOTNet but digging into the code just show a small Enumerable class [Enumerable](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs).

**Question**

Where is the source code for the following Extention Method?

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

Sub-Question 1  Where is the full frameWork Version?

Sub-Question 2  Where is the .net core Version?

Comment: If you do this often, have a look at ReSharper, it has tooling to analyse these things.

Comment: @Stefan the problem here is the at the input that is coming in is from something I don't control. so the Resharper static analysis would not work in this case

Comment: now I need to decide what is better. checking if it is already a list, or doing the enumeration twice.

Comment: Actually, it most likely better to just handle as the Enumerable.

Comment: I'd suggest using `IReadOnlyList<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. This allows consumers to not worry about double enumeration, but makes it clear you don't want them to edit the list.

Comment: @mjwills I can see that in the full Frame work source             public List<TResult> ToList()
            {
                var list = new List<TResult>();

                foreach (TSource item in _source)
                {
                    list.Add(_selector(item));
                }

                return list;
            }

Comment: this will move the object to a new list

Comment: Answer to Q2: https://source.dot.net/ is a great online tool for .dot net (.net core) source code.

The source code for `ToList<T>()` depends upon the type.  See https://source.dot.net/#q=Linq%20ToList

Comment: I meant: use the decompiler.

Comment: @Stefan OK got it needed to does some setup found here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Decompiled_Code.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Question 1 Where is the full frameWork Version?

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L947

> Question 2 Where is the .net core Version?

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8750960d3fafa46a9b838c351e995a01fa8b599f/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs#L23

Above are links for two `ToList` implementations (there are others).

They cover .NET Framework and .NET Core.

> Where I'm looking to see if putting a  .ToList() on an IEnumerable
>   which might or might not be a list will incur a performance hit if the
>   Object is already a List.

It definitely will create a new list, as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8):

> **Creates** a List from an IEnumerable.

You can also test this for yourself, by by calling `ToList` on a `List<int>`. Then change the new `List<int>`. *The original `List<int>` isn't changed - so it must have created a new `List<int>`.*

Answer (score 5):

https://source.dot.net/ is a great online tool for .dot net (.net core) source code.

The source code for `ToList<T>()` depends upon the type.  See https://source.dot.net/#q=Linq%20ToList

Comment: This is a Great tool thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Here it is: [`Enumerable.ToList`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs,e276d6892241255b). What do you mean by *depends upon the type*? The result of the method is always a new `List<T>`.

Comment: @mjwills all of these `ToList` are internal methods of .NET Core. Only the one I linked is public.

Comment: @mjwills I don't understand what ❝the source code depends upon the type❞ means. It is nonsensical to me. Btw I upvoted the answer too, for the [link](https://source.dot.net/).